# How can I get rid of the outer parameters of a JSON String?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json string returned from an API call that looks like this

```
{"study":{"moleculeDescription":"RONTALIZUMAB","protocolTitle":"IMM","protocolNumber":"GA00806","studyName":"Interferon alpha in SLE Phase II LCM Option","therapeuticArea":"INFLAMMATORY,AUTOIMMUNE&BONE","startDate":"2009-03-25","endDate":"2013-08-22"}}
```

I want to be able to use something like what I have below to cycle through the json string and assign the values to input fields on the page.

```
function doStuff() {
        var myTest = document.getElementById('{!$Component.jsonStr}');

        for( k in myTest ){
            document.getElementById(k).value = myTest[k];
            }
        }
```

However, it only works when my json string (var myTest) looks like this (see below, doesn't have the outer {"study":} parameter)

```
{"moleculeDescription":"RONTALIZUMAB","protocolTitle":"IMM","protocolNumber":"GA00806","studyName":"Interferon alpha in SLE Phase II LCM Option","therapeuticArea":"INFLAMMATORY,AUTOIMMUNE&BONE","startDate":"2009-03-25","endDate":"2013-08-22"}
```

Does anyone know how I can eliminate the outer section of my json string so that I can work with the inner section? Or is there a better way, such as modifying the for statement? Thanks for any help, and sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm a newb.

Comment: what happens if you try and access the study object and then loop through the properties of that instead? ie for ( k in myTest.study)

Comment: for( k in myTest.study )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = {"study":{"moleculeDescription":"RONTALIZUMAB","protocolTitle":"IMM","protocolNumber":"GA00806","studyName":"Interferon alpha in SLE Phase II LCM Option","therapeuticArea":"INFLAMMATORY,AUTOIMMUNE&BONE","startDate":"2009-03-25","endDate":"2013-08-22"}};

var y = x.study;
```

**y** will be the required `var`

Better thing to do is

```
for( k in myTest.study )
{
     document.getElementById(k).value = myTest[k];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following

```
for (var key in myTest) {
  if (myTest.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var localSet = myTest[key];
    // .. here goes your code to iterate through inner object
  }
}
```